# Cumulative Product Sum for numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I was curious if there was a quick way of calculating the cumulative product sum for a given array in Python. I understand that numpy has both the `cumsum` and `cumprod` functions, but neither seems to work in conjunction with my case. My iterative sequence is as follows, where *t* is a time index:

**X_{t+1} = X_{t} * (B_{t+1} - B_{t}) + X_t**

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your question is to make X given B and initial value of X (X_1). Is this right?

Comment: Given an initial value of X at time *t*, the sequence for every term thereafter is defined as the product of the X at time *t* and the difference of two terms B, plus the X value at time *t*

Comment: Is the entire B vector known? If not, there isn't enough information to compute X_t.

Comment: the entire B vector is known, the X vector is only known from initialization *t=0*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this solution, I will assume the vector B is known.
The equation for X can be simplified as follows

```
X_(t+1) = (B_(t+1) - B_t) X_t + X_t
X_(t+1) = ((B_(t+1) - B_t) + 1) X_t

let C = B[1:] - B[:-1] + 1.
```

Now the dynamic equation is

```
X_(t+1) = C_t X_t
```

Observe the behaviour of the equation

```
X_1 = C_0 X_0
X_2 = C_1 C_0 X_0
X_3 = C_2 C_1 C_0 X_0
```

From the pattern above, we get

```
X_n = C_(n-1) ... C_0 X_0
```

This means, if you are just after a particular state, you do not need to explicitly compute every preceding state.
To get the product of elements in a numpy array, simply use `numpy.prod`.  The snippet below shows how to compute X for a given point and how to compute X at all values for `t`

```
import numpy as np

# provide for B and X_0 yourself.

C = B[1:] - B[:-1] + 1
X = np.cumprod(C) * X_0   # compute the entire X vector at once.
X_5 = np.prod(C[:5]) * X_0 # compute X_5 only
```

That's it! no explicit looping or recursion.

Comment: Well seen . + 1

Comment: It should be `C = B[1:] - B[:-1] + 1`. `B[:-2]` will drop last 2 elements

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Since X_2, X_3, .... should be calculated in each time, loop should be used, but B_diff ([B_2-B_1, B_3-B_2, ...]) is calculated efficiently in advances.

```
def make_X(initial_X, B):
    B_diff = B[1:] - B[:-1] + 1
    X = [initial_X]
    for t in range(len(B_diff)):
        next_X = B_diff[t] * X[-1]
        X.append(next_X)
    return X

# Test 
make_X(1, np.array([1, 2, 3, 4]))
```

Comment: I already had something similar to this, was hoping there was a quick array method to implement. Thanks, anyway tho

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately decided to work with a numpy apply custom function, since I need to use this across a matrix:

```
# for calculating the series
def myFunc(arr:np.array, initial:int, size:int):
    temp = initial
    new_arr = [0]*size
    for i in range(size):
        new_arr[i] = temp + (temp * arr[i])
        temp += temp * arr[i]
    return np.array(new_arr) 

# for implementing it across my matrix 
np.apply_along_axis(myFunc, 0, arr, initial, size)
```

Comment: `apply_along_axis` may be handy in this case, but it isn't a speed improvement (over a more explicit loop).